# Transfer data from a UITableCellView and UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController with its own class *HomeVC*, containing multiple Cells, one of which uses its own class *NewsFeedCell*. This cell contains a vertical UIScrollView that displays pics. I want the user to, when he clicks the the row, trigger a segue to a VC with the picture. I created a *currentPage* variable in *NewsFeedCell* class, which obviously shows which page, and which picture, is the UIScrollView showing.

In the *HomeVC*, i have this:

```
class HomeVC: UITableViewController {
(...)
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
 (...)   
 if indexPath.row == 0 { //The cell containing the UIScrollView
        print(NewsFeedCell.currentPage) // I used "print" to simply the shown code 
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that xcode gives me an error saying ***Instance member "currentPage" cannot be used on type "NewsFeedCell"***.

I tried printing the value of currentPage to the console in the code of *NewsFeedCell*, and it worked.

Btw, the variable is declared inside the *NewsFeedCell* and has its first value assigned under ***awakeFromnNib()*** to 0, and the second  time under:

```
func scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(_ scrollView: UIScrollView){
    currentPage = Int(floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - cellWidth / 2) / cellWidth)) + 1
    print(currentPage)
}
```

Please HELP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you created `currentPage` as an instance variable, meaning that each object of type `NewsFeedCell` has its own version. To access it, you have to have a reference to an individual `NewsFeedCell`, like this:

```
var myCell = NewsFeedCell()
print(myCell.currentPage)
```

and its value will be different for every cell. If you want there to be only a single `currentPage` for all `NewsFeedCell`s, you declare it as static, like this (in the NewsFeedCell class):

```
static var currentPage: Int = 0
```

then you can access it using `NewsFeedCell.currentPage` as you have been.

The reason you were able to `print(currentPage)` from a function inside of `NewsFeedCell` is that that function is an *instance method*. Each instance has its own copy, and it prints the currentPage for the specific instance that the method was called on.

It's not quite clear to me what exactly you're trying to do with `currentPage`, so I'm not sure whether you want a static variable or an instance variable. In general, if you want there to be a single version of the variable that's accessible from anywhere, make it static. If you want each cell to have its own value, make it a regular instance variable.

Comment: Thanks very much! It worked. But i'm encountering a new problem: as the UIScrollView covers up the entire cell, the app doesn't detect any touch on that cell. Is there any fix for this or no?

Comment: @FayezHellani I suggest asking that as a separate question.